# How To Make Toast Throw Out Custom Errors

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, react-toastify

I am using MongoDB and I installed react toastify to show errors from my backend for sign in but I can not seem to show them. How do I fix this issue? because I can output toast messages but not the custom errors I have.

js file where my toast messages are accessed

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      try {
          const {data} = await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_LOGIN, {
            username, password
          });

          if (data.success === true) {
            setValues({username: '', password: ''})
            toast.success("Sign in successfully");
            //save user in local storage
            if (typeof window !== "undefined") {
              localStorage.setItem("token", JSON.stringify(data));
            }
            navigate("/map");
          }
      } catch (err) {
        //logs undefined
        console.log(`This is the error: ${err.response.data.error}`);
        toast.error(`There is an error: ${err.response.data.error}`);
      }
    } 

return (
    <div className='loginContainer'>
    <div className='logo'></div>
    <AddLocationAltIcon/>
    Pin
    <form className='loginForm'>
    <input type='text' className='usernameE' placeholder='username' onChange={handleChange('username')}/>
    <input type='password' className='passwordE' placeholder='password' onChange={handleChange('password')} />
    <button className='loginBtn' onClick={handleSubmit} type="submit">Login</button>
    <button onClick={() => navigate('/register')} className="loginRegister">
    Sign Up
    </button>
    </form>
    </div>
  )
```

js file with my custom errors

```
exports.signin = async (req, res, next)=> {
    try {
        const {username, password} = req.body;
        //if no username and password
        if (!username || !password) {
            return next(new ErrorResponse(`Username and password are required`, 404))
        }
        //check username
        const user = await User.findOne({username});
        if (!user) {
            return next(new ErrorResponse(`Invalid credentials`, 404))
        }

        //verify user password
        const isMatched = await user.comparePassword(password);
        if (!isMatched) {
            return next(new ErrorResponse(`Cannot log in, check your credentials`, 404))
        }

        generateToken(user, 200, res);
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return next(new ErrorResponse(`Cannot log in, check your credentials`, 404))
    }

}
```

ErrorResponse Class

```
class ErrorResponse extends Error {
    constructor(message, statusCode) {
        super(message);
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }
}

module.exports = ErrorResponse;
```

Comment: Is the the console before this comment `this is supposed to display error not be undefined.` is logging correctly the error?

Comment: The console is logging undefined and not giving me the error. I will make it more clear.

Comment: Try logging just `err`.